# Killing current block in C mode

Tags: emacs

Is there an easy way to configure a single key-combination to kill the content of the inner-most block currently under the cursor. In other words

```
if (foo) {
  bar;
  baz;
}
```

would transform into

```
if (foo) {
}
```

when hitting the key-combination with the cursor anywhere inside the block. Similarly, I would like to be able to have one key-combination to kill the content of the guard of the if-clause if the cursor was anywhere on `foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Install [expand-region](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el): `M-x package-install expand-region`, and add `(require 'expand-region)` to your `.emacs`.

The function you are looking for is `er/inside-pairs`, which will expand until hitting `()` `{}`, `""`, etc. To bind it to a specific key command like `C-=`, put this in your `.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-=") 'er/inside-pairs)
```

Comment: This is cool. I noticed one interesting thing with this. If you've got a function `f(int foo, char bar)` and I expand-region on `int` it expands the word `int`. If I expand-region again it expands all of `int foo, char bar` instead of just `int foo`. Any idea how to get the latter behavior?

Comment: Nope, I don't think that's a built-in expansion in `expand-region`. You can call this function: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3NF7STBM There seems to be some support for adding extra expansions to `expand-region`, but I've never messed with that.